# Angular is good practice to re-use service among components

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have a service:

```
export class LangService {
  public test = "hi";
}
```

A parent component:

```
import {LangService} from "./services/lang.service";
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private _lang: LangService) {
    _lang.test = "bye";
  }
}
```

And a child component:

```
import {LangService} from "./services/lang.service";
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private _lang: LangService) {
    console.log(_lang.test); //Here is printing "bye" and not "hi" exactly as I'm expecting
  }
}
```

Both components are using the same instance of my **LangService**

I have read that to have a correct component interaction, Angular documentation suggests some ways, one of them is to comunicate using a service and subscribing to service's observables

My question is. **Is it a good practice to comunicate components using just service's variables instead of service's subscribers?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not like that you select `Observable` or any of `Subject`(then subscribe to them) instead of using plain variables.

When you got some value from service by previously subscribe to it and observe you expecting that this value will change over time or by certain actions and then you will be noticed about it. 
It's better way to do that instead of checking in component manually by eg. 10 sec or after clicking on button.

Comment: If we don't want to use observables is it still safe to use only variables in injectables ?

Comment: By "to use only variables in injectables" I understand that you inject service which have some members that you can access. I belive it is safe until you know when you need to check & get this value since you are not observing changes on this value.

Comment: I understand. So, in my view I'm doing something like {{ _lang.test }} then any change in service properties will be correctly rendered on my view.  In summary, for this especific example, using only variables is not considered a bad practice?